# Resetting wireless adapter in Windows 10 with regular user privileges from command line

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, wireless-networking

In Windows 10, wireless network adapter can be reset via GUI following "Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections" and selecting "Diagnose" from connection's context menu. If there is a network issue (or wireless adapter is not connected to any network), Windows resets the adapter. This process requires no admin privileges, no driver re-installation, and no restart. Can this adapter reset process be run via a cmd script and what are the commands?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to correct a Wired or Wireless network problem on a computer, you need to run TCP/IP Reset.

You need to have Administrative Credentials to do this.

> Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
>
> (1) netsh int IP reset c:\resetlog.txt
>
> (2) ipconfig /flushdns
>
> (3) Restart the computer.

So can this process be run from a [user] command line?  No, you cannot do this.

If you just need to restart the adapter (normally does not fix underlying issues), you might be able to use a Power Shell Script to do it, but even it appears to need Admin credentials. This means all command line methods I have reviewed require Admin credentials.

Most of the parameters below are optional so you can likely find a simple form of the cmdlet that you can use.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/restart-netadapter?view=win10-ps

> Restart-NetAdapter
>
> ```
>    [-Name] <String[]>
>    [-IncludeHidden]
>    [-PassThru]
>    [-CimSession <CimSession[]>]
>    [-ThrottleLimit <Int32>]
>    [-AsJob]
>    [-WhatIf]
>    [-Confirm]
>    [<CommonParameters>]
> ```

Comment: I can do it from GUI as a non-admin. Only the Wi-Fi adapter is reset. No restarts necessary. If it can be done from GUI, most likely it can be done from the command line.

Comment: I think that is just restarting the adapter.  A true reset requires the process I laid out. Simply restarting the adapter may solve some but not all issues- the more difficult issues require proper reset.

Comment: Well, many issues can be solved by formatting the hard drive and reinstalling the OS from scratch. I asked about a very particular process, which I want to be able to run from the command line, not about some other process.

Comment: I don’t think you need to reformat the hard drive to fix the TCP/IP stack.  I have not had to do that.

Comment: Exactly. And I did not have to use admin privileges nor any restarts, as I indicated in both the topic and summary. Sure thing some problems require both, but that is besides the point.

Comment: I have looked at several articles for command line restart of a network adapter, and they require Admin Command to do that. The most promising was a  Power Shell cmdlet that does not say it needs admin rights. I have added it to my answer.

Comment: It did not work. I got "Permission Denied" error

Comment: So then you will just need to use the GUI method